# How do I get XML values from XSLT to HTML to another HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

I have an XSLT file that creates the HTML to output on the HTML page. However, I need to get information from the node that was selected, and pass that onto another page.

I have index.html which renders out into a div called 'spreadView' which has numerous links in it that I render out in the XSLT file, but want to click on a link and it takes to me to view the song by the artist (need to pass artist and song name).

Any ideas how?

Here is the data in the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>

     <body>
       <div class="row">

        <xsl:for-each select="lfm/tracks/track">
         <xsl:sort  order="descending" data-type="number" select="playcount"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 8">
               <xsl:value-of select="result"/>

                       <div class="col s12 m3">
                             <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-image">
                                   <img>
                                   <xsl:attribute name="src">
                                      <xsl:value-of select="image[4]"/>
                                   </xsl:attribute>
                                   </img>
                                   <span class="card-title"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                   <p><b>Song: </b> <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                   </p>

                                   <p><b>Artist: </b><xsl:value-of select="artist/name"/>
                                   </p>

                                   <p><b>Playcount: </b> 
                                      <xsl:value-of select="playcount"/>
                                   </p>
                                </div>

                             </div>
                       </div>


             </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </div>
     </body>
  </html>
```

index.html: 
https://jsfiddle.net/8pqk5k35/

Comment: Could you add index.htm example?

Comment: just done @Alexander